# Two way data binding in Vue: Unable to update the Parent component from the child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, two-way-binding

I got the following two components:

Parent:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row class="text-center">
      <v-col cols="12" class="parent">
        <p>Ich bin der Parent component</p>
        <button @click="changeDetail" :name.sync="name">Change Details</button>
        <Child v-bind:name="name"></Child>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import Child from "./Child";
export default {
  name: "Parent",

  data: () => ({
    name: "test"
  }),
  methods: {
    changeDetail() {
      this.name = "Updated from Parent";
    }
  },
  components: {
    Child
  }
};
</script>
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row class="text-center">
      <v-col cols="12">
        <p>My name is: {{ name}}</p>
        <button @click="resetname">Reset the name</button>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  //   props: ["name"],
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    newname: "Updated from Child"
  }),
  methods: {
    resetname() {
      this.$emit("update:name", this.newname);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

As far as I read here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier, I should use update and sync to pass props from the child back to the parent. However it does not work. I don´t understand what´s wrong here. What am I missing?

Comment: This is where you can probably rely on something like Vuex.  http://vuex.vuejs.org takes a lot of the work out of shared states.

Comment: I know, but I still would really like to understand this ;-)

Comment: In `Parent`, you've bound `:name.sync` to `<button>` when it should be on `<Child>`.

Comment: That´s it, dumb me. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually best to not bind your template to the prop but a computed property instead to ensure the data is accessed and modified externally.  It will also simplify your code a bit so that you don't have to trigger updates.

#### Parent:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row class="text-center">
      <v-col cols="12" class="parent">
        <p>Ich bin der Parent component</p>
        <button @click="changeDetail">Change Details</button>
        <Child v-bind:name.sync="name"></Child>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import Child from "./Child";
export default {
  name: "Parent",

  data: () => ({
    name: "test"
  }),
  methods: {
    changeDetail() {
      this.name = "Updated from Parent";
    }
  },
  components: {
    Child
  }
};
</script>
```

#### Child:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row class="text-center">
      <v-col cols="12">
        <p>My name is: {{ currentName }}</p>
        <button @click="resetname">Reset the name</button>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  //   props: ["name"],
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
     //Be careful with fat arrow functions for data
     //Because the value of *this* isn't the component, 
     //but rather the parent scope.
  }),
  computed: {
    currentName: {
        get() { return this.name },
        set(value) { this.$emit("update:name", value); }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    resetname() {
      this.currentName = "updated from child";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```